# Solving system of three equations

Tags: solution-verification, systems-of-equations, matrix-equations

Given system of equations:
$$\frac{2}{x}+\frac{3}{y}+\frac{10}{z}=4$$
$$\frac{4}{x}-\frac{6}{y}+\frac{5}{z}=1$$
$$\frac{6}{x}+\frac{9}{y}-\frac{20}{z}=2$$

I'll use matrices to solve these. We can write the system as:
$$AX=B$$
$$A^{-1}AX=A^{-1}B$$
$$X=A^{-1}B$$ where $X$ is our variable matrix. For simplicity, let $\frac{1}{x}=\alpha, \frac{1}{y}=\beta,\frac{1}{z}=\gamma $

Thus we have to solve:

$$2\alpha+3\beta+10\gamma=4$$
$$4\alpha-6\beta+5\gamma=1$$
$$6\alpha+9\beta-20\gamma=2$$

$A$ is simply the matrix formed using the coefficients of the variables:

$$A=\begin{bmatrix}2&3&10\\4&-6&5\\6&9&-20\end{bmatrix}$$

$X$ is the variable matrix

$$X=\begin{bmatrix}\alpha\\\beta\\\gamma\end{bmatrix}$$

$B$ is the matrix formed by right hand side values of the respective equations:

$$B=\begin{bmatrix}4\\1\\2\end{bmatrix}$$

Thus, our system of equations becomes:

$$\begin{bmatrix}2&3&10\\4&-6&5\\6&9&-20\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}\alpha\\\beta\\\gamma\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}4\\1\\2\end{bmatrix}$$

Now, we just need to find $A^{-1}.$ Finding cofactors for A

Cofactor $ A=\begin{bmatrix}75&110&72\\150&-100&0\\75&30&-24\end{bmatrix}$

$A^{-1}=\frac{1}{1200}\begin{bmatrix}75&150&75\\110&-100&30\\72&0&-24\end{bmatrix}$

$\Rightarrow \begin{bmatrix}\alpha\\\beta\\\gamma\end{bmatrix}=\frac{1}{1200}\begin{bmatrix}75&150&75\\110&-100&30\\72&0&-24\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}4\\1\\2\end{bmatrix}$

$\Rightarrow \begin{bmatrix}\alpha\\\beta\\\gamma\end{bmatrix}=\frac{1}{1200}\begin{bmatrix}600\\400\\240\end{bmatrix}$

$\alpha=\frac{1}{2},\beta=\frac{1}{3},\gamma=\frac{1}{5}$

$\Rightarrow x=2,y=3,z=5$

My problem- This method seems unnecessarily lengthy. What better ways are there to solve such systems of equations?

Comment: [Cramer's Rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cramer's_rule)

Comment: Row reduction.  Subtract rwice the first equation from the second, and three times the first from the third, to get two equations in just $\beta$ and $\gamma$, which is simpler.

Comment: Look up Gauss elimination

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the comments, subtracting thrice the first equation from the third gives $-50\gamma=-10$ or $\gamma=\frac15$. Subtracting twice the first equation from the second and substituting (and negating) gives
$12\beta=4$ or $\beta=\frac13$. Substituting the known values into the first equation finally gives $\alpha=\frac12$, so $(x,y,z)=(2,3,5)$.